# How to check if a string is of yyyy-yyyy format

Tags: java, java-time

I have an `ArrayList` as below:

```
dates : [
"1981-1990",
"1971-1980",
"1991-2000"
]
```

I would like to perform a check: to see if the values in the list are year-ranges or not.

**EDITED** : Sometimes I get proper dates format like 'yyyy-MM-dd' and sometimes year-range. I just want my function to work in both conditions. It should identify it as a date if a date is present or year range. That's all

Comment: What have your tried yourself? Your business logic should decide minimum and maximum value of the year.

Comment: maybe you could use a regular expression and then apply it for each item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**Year**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) with [**Year::isBefore**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#isBefore-java.time.Year-) from **java-time** api like so :

```
String[] ranges = {"1981-1990", "1971-1980", "1991-2000"};
for (String range : ranges) {
    String[] dates = range.split("-");
    if (Year.parse(dates[0]).isBefore(Year.parse(dates[1]))) {
        System.out.println("Correct range");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong range");
    }
}
```

---

After your edit, I would go with this solution here :

```
String[] dates = {"1981-1990", "2020-02-25", "1971-1980", "1998-02-25", "1991-2000"};
for (String date : dates) {
    if (date.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{4}")) {
        String[] split = date.split("-");

        if (Year.parse(split[0]).isBefore(Year.parse(split[1]))) {
            System.out.println("Correct range");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong range");
        }
    } else {
        try {
            LocalDate.parse(date);
            System.out.println("Correct date");
        } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
            System.out.println("Wrong date");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also checked the size of dates array with 2, just to be sure that it is a year range. Added two methods like : if(isYearRange() || isISODate() ) { //do comething }. Where i cj=heck year range with your previous code and ISO Date with a date formatter

Answer (score 0):

Your `ArrayList` has `String` elements, so, you need to call the [.split()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/) method for each of them while you are looping your `ArrayList`. The `split` method returns an array of strings, so, on the resulting array you check the length. If the length is 2, then you have two years. If the length is 5, then you have two full dates. If the length is 4, then one of the values is a full date and the other is a year. So,

```
for (int index = 0; index < myArrayList.size(); index++) {
    String[] items = myArrayList.get(index).split();
    if (items.length == 2) {/*Two years*/}
    else if (items.length == 5) {/*Two full dates*/}
    else if (items.length == 4) {
        if (items[1].length() == 4) {/*The first is a year, the second a full date*/}
        else {/*The first is a full date, the second is a year*/}
    }
}
```